# Display ONE taxonomy and its assigned pages

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, page-template

Quite a straight-forward question but I haven't been able to find a solution. I have created a page which lists categories within a taxonomy called **'Themes'**. I now want each link in the list to point towards an index page which displays all of the pages for that particular category.

The way I see it, it's a bit like a search results page, because I only want to create one template page for the results, but the results will vary depending on what Taxonomy category is clicked.

E.g. This is what I want to happen:

The post-type is called **Events**.

Within **Events** there is a taxonomy called **Themes**.

**Themes** has a number of categories such as **Boat**, **Fishing**, **Walking**, **Eating** etc.

On one of the pages, user clicks on the **Boat** category listed.

User is then taken to a page which displays all of my post-type pages within the **Boat** category under the **Themes** taxonomy.

Hope this is clear, if you need any clarification just let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quiet easy using WP page template and taxonomy templates (Why do you want to display all results on one page? I think it is better when you URLs will have some logical structure).

You can create new [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) and use [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Taxonomy Terms
*/

get_header();

?>
<div id="primary">
    <div role="main" id="content">
<?php

        wp_list_categories( 'title_li=Themes&taxonomy=theme' );

?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

get_footer();
```

This will outpout the list of all the terms (categories) for your custom taxonomy "theme".

Additionally you can use WordPress [templates hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to modify the display of others template. e.x. *taxonomy-theme.php*

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JohnnyPea, but although this lists a particular taxonomy category, I also need to be able to style the results, rather than have a simple list of items.

Have a look at this code:

[link](git://gist.github.com/1222153.git)

Comment: I've managed to grab EVERY taxonomy category in a way that allows me to style it accordingly, however I need to know how I display only ONE taxonomy category which depends on what link the user clicked on the previous page. I think my example in the original question makes it clearer to understand

Comment: Your link is not working and I still don't understand.